# Фильтр вставить в модальное окно

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

есть модальное окно

```
toggle: function() {
        var self= this;
        var myDialog = new Dialog({
            title: 'My Dialog',
            content:'<div class="data-action">' + this.state.name + '</div>' + '<br>' +
        '<div class="center margin-top">' +
        '<button data-action="cancel">Cancel</button>' +
        ' ' +
        '<button data-action="ok">OK</button>' +
        '</div>',
            style: 'width: 300px; height: 1000px;'
        });

        myDialog.show();
```

есть фильтр

```
'get state': function() {
        var state = {};
        var self = this;

        Object.keys(this.filters)
            .forEach(function(filterName) {
                var filter = self.filters[filterName];
                state[filterName] = filter.state.values;
            });

        return state;
    },

    'set state': function(value) {
        var self = this;

        Object.keys(this.filters)
            .forEach(function(filterName) {
                var filter = self.filters[filterName];
                filter.state = value[filterName];
            });
    }
```

Как такой фильтр впихнуть в это окно он протсо пишет  Object в окне вместо фильтра.?

```
define(['ipsp/util/class-construct', 'ipsp/util/dom-builder', 'ipsp/ui/widget', './filter', './helper', 'dijit/Dialog'], function(classConstruct, domBuilder, Widget, Filter, HELPER, Dialog) {
'use strict';

function RouteFilter(options, context) {
    Widget.apply(this, arguments);

    this.context = context;

    this.filters = Object.create(null);

    for (var prop in options) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(options, prop)) {
            this.filters[prop] = new Filter(
                {
                    name: prop,
                    values: HELPER.FILTERING.MARSHALLING[prop](options[prop], 'in')
                },
                this
            );
        }
    }

    this.dom = domBuilder(
        '<div class="filter-editor short">' +
            '<button data-action="expand"></button>' +
            '<br>' +
            '<div class="wrap-filters-table"></div>' +
            '<br>' +
        '</div>'
    )[0];


    this.wrapFiltersTableNode = this.dom.querySelector('.wrap-filters-table');
    this.buttonNode = this.dom.querySelector('[data-action="expand"]');

    this.buttonNode.addEventListener('click', this.toggle.bind(this));
}

RouteFilter.defaultParams = function(routeFilterDataQuery) {
    var params = Object.create(null);

    routeFilterDataQuery.data
        .forEach(function(filterItem) {
            params[filterItem.id] = '';
        });

    return params;
};

return classConstruct(RouteFilter, {

    instaniateDom: function() {
        var filters = Object.keys(this.filters).sort();

        // пересортируем так, чтобы валюты, страны и суммы транзакций были сверху
        HELPER.FILTERING.PRIORITY_FILTERS
            .slice()
            .reverse()
            .forEach(function(filterName) {
                var filterIdx = filters.indexOf(filterName);

                if (filterIdx !== -1) {
                    filters.splice(filterIdx, 1);
                    filters.unshift(filterName);
                }
            });

        var self = this;
        filters.forEach(function(filterName) {
            var filter = self.filters[filterName];

            filter.instaniateDom();
            if (HELPER.FILTERING.PRIORITY_FILTERS.indexOf(filterName) !== -1) {
                filter.append(self.wrapFiltersTableNode);
            } else {
                filter.append(self.dom);
            }
        });

        this.updateButtonLabel();
    },

    toggle: function() {
        var self= this;
        var myDialog = new Dialog({
            title: 'My Dialog',
            content:'<div class="data-action">' + this.text + '</div>' + '<br>' +
        '<div class="center margin-top">' +
        '<button data-action="cancel">Cancel</button>' +
        ' ' +
        '<button data-action="ok">OK</button>' +
        '</div>',
            style: 'width: 300px; height: 1000px;'
        });

        myDialog.show();
        this.dom.classList.toggle('short');
        this.updateButtonLabel();
    },

    updateButtonLabel: function() {
        this.buttonNode.textContent = (this.dom.classList.contains('short') ? 'Expand' : 'Contract');
    },

    'get state': function() {
        var state = {};
        var self = this;

        Object.keys(this.filters)
            .forEach(function(filterName) {
                var filter = self.filters[filterName];
                state[filterName] = filter.state.values;
            });

        return state;
    },

    'set state': function(value) {
        var self = this;

        Object.keys(this.filters)
            .forEach(function(filterName) {
                var filter = self.filters[filterName];
                filter.state = value[filterName];
            });
    }
}, Widget);
```

});
Вот весь файл js мб я чего не так понял и не так пытаюсь фильтр запилить

Comment: Вопрос требует доработки. Сейчас не понятно, с чем вы имеете дело, что пытаетесь выполнить и какой результат получить.

Comment: @Константин Башаркевич Изменил